# patchValue of type=time input - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular10

I am not able to use patchValue on the input of a form group control.
I have tried this :

```html
  <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Duration (HH:MM)</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="time" formControlName="durationCtrl">
  </mat-form-field>
```

```js
this.myGroup.get('durationCtrl').patchValue('20:20')
```

and this

```js
this.myGroup.patchValue({
    durationCtrl: "0:20"
})
```

I'm able to read from the form. When I read it after setting it manually, it returns a string in the format HH:MM, like "04:20".
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Edit: turns out the issue is purely visual, the value of the control is what it's supposed to be but it does not display the corresponding value. Still a problem but now I have no idea how this can happen.

Comment: Try this: this.myGroup.patchValue({durationCtrl: newvalue})

Comment: did not work unfortunately. i'll still change to this because it looks more clean, thanks

Comment: here You have example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avwa3m?file=src/app/app.component.ts and if You have diferent time like you set check localization,

Comment: I see with this example that the problem must be somewhere else, i'll look around and see. many thanks !